# Locked our of Windows Server 2012 R2 after AD installation

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance and I just installed Active Directory. After installation, I set up the server as Domain Controller, set up a couple of admin accounts, and went to sleep. The server was fine until the next day when I tried to log in, the login screen gets stuck at Welcome, after that it displays the following message: **Please wait for the User Profile Service**. After a long time it displays this message: **Applying User Settings**.

The screen remains the same for a long time and sometimes it displays the following error: `The task you are trying to do can't be completed because Remote Desktop Services is currently busy. Please try again in a few minutes. Other users should still be able to log on.`

Please help as this is a production server and it is now unreachable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Power the server off and on. Then try again.

Comment: I did that, no changes.

Comment: Are you looking at it via Remote Desktop? What if you look at the actual console? if it's an azure machine, my sympathies - if you can get the Powershell console, you could try `Restart-Service -Name RemoteAccess`. Also, why are you installing 2012 R2? it's outside mainstream support, and there was a bug with unpatched versions of RDP